# Find and/or Access values in a C# List container

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I did find some solutions related to this problem but it's still not working for me.

I have a list of integer arrays "numbers" that has some integer sequences as follows:

```
        List<int[]> numbers;
        numbers = new List<int[]>();
        numbers.Add(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14 }); // 0
        numbers.Add(new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 }); // 1
        numbers.Add(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14 }); // 2
```

Then, after processing some data I will get a targeted sequence "MyList":

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    if (TempImg.Data[i, j, 0] == 0)
                        MyList.Add(k);
                    k++;}}
```

Then, I want to check if this targeted sequence is within my original List "numbers". I convert it first to an integer array "results" as follows:

```
int[] results = MyList.ToArray<int>();
```

and then tend to find it in the list as follows:

```
        k = numbers.IndexOf(results);
        Console.WriteLine(k);
```

the output is (-1) but NOT the actual index of the matching sequence.

-1 means not found, while when I display it to the console I find that it's the exact matching sequence ..  I would love to know why it's not working..

I also tried to do this to iterate the original list and find the matching sequence then display its index. But also didn't work:

```
        //for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count(); i++)
        //{
        //    if (results == numbers[i])
        //        Console.WriteLine(i);
        //}
```

Thank you much

Comment: Could you output what the results array looks like? Also what is `TempImg.Data`?

Comment: what `List.IndexOf` is doing in this case is trying to find and object that is equal to one of the elements in the list. Yet you're asking to find an array of ints (`int[]`), not a single `int` so of course, it's not found. There is no such function that will do what you're asking. You need to write it yourself.

Comment: I can output you the results. `code`TempImg.Data `code` is the array of pixels of an image (here I am checking which pixel of the 3x5 image are black). Then imagine the results (MyList in this case) are the pixels { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14 }. Then I wanna check the matching sequence and get its index. Thank you @John and @Gread. I got it now. It's comparing the memory addresses but not the actual values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `IndexOf`, the two arrays are compared as references, not as values. This means that since the arrays are at different locations in memory, they will not be equal when compared using the `IndexOf` method (even though their elements are equal).

You can find the index using the `FindIndex` and `SequenceEqual` methods from Linq:

```
numbers.FindIndex(collection => collection.SequenceEqual(results));
```

This will compare the elements of the arrays and return the index of the first array in `numbers` with matching elements.

Answer (score 3):

What does the `List<T>.IndexOf` method?

> Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of
>   the first occurrence within the entire List.

Two arrays that contain the same elements are not the same object. They are two completely different objects. The variables that "hold" these arrays have two different references in the memory of your program. These references points to two different locations.

One workaround to your problem, it could be something like this:

```
var indexOfResults = -1;
for(var index=0; index<numbers.Size; i++)
{
    if(results.Length == numbers[index].Length 
       && results.Except(numbers[index]).Count() == 0)
    { 
        indexOfResults = index;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it. You are correct. It's comparing the memory addresses but not the actual values (which is never equal/match) Thank you much @Christos

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)